# Why mysql (not in) faster than without subquery?

Tags: mysql

I can write a query with two differents types:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `pictures` 
WHERE `field_id` NOT IN (SELECT `field_id` 
                         FROM `table` 
                         WHERE `confirm` = 0)
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM `pictures` 
WHERE `field_id` NOT IN (12,56,435,44,25,52,876,99)
```

But the second example are very faster!
What is the reason for being faster?

Comment: The reason is that MySQL has to do less work...

Comment: I suspect what you're really after is `INNER JOIN `

Comment: Really? My vote's for an outer join!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good performance rule of thumb: doing less work takes less time.

In the simpler example, the MySQL engine executes exactly 1 query:

```
-- Execute the main query (takes time M)
SELECT * 
FROM `pictures` 
WHERE `field_id` NOT IN (12,56,435,44,25,52,876,99)
```

In the more complex example, the MySQL engine executes 2 queries:

```
-- Execute the subquery (takes time S)
SELECT `field_id` FROM `table` WHERE `confirm` = 0;
-- => (12,56,435,44,25,52,876,99)

-- Plug the subquery results into the main query (takes time M)
SELECT * 
FROM `pictures` 
WHERE `field_id` NOT IN (12,56,435,44,25,52,876,99);
```

The simpler example takes about time `M` in total, whereas the more complex example takes about time `S + M`, plus maybe a bit more overhead to plug everything, and `S + M` is greater than `M`.

Comment: This is true. I used to think the ideal situation was to get everything in one query. In practice I discovered it's not.